# I need to move text down but without a line moving with it and i want to allow a line to clip through an image

Tags: html, css

I want to move text down but without moving a line I have also I want to be able to see the rest of a line through an image I cannot see the line if it is to close to the image

my code:

```css
.NavigationTable {
  clear: Both;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.ImageLogo {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.line {
  line-height: 10px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <meta charset="UTF=8">
  <meta name="description" content="denvware software solutions">
  <title>Denvware</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)">
  <header>
    <img src="Logo1denv.png" width="170" style="background-color:antiquewhite" class="ImageLogo" />

    <table>
      <tr class="NavigationTable">
        <td>Home</td>
        <td>About</td>
        <td>Contact</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </header>
  <main>

    <hr class="line" style="position:relative; top:100px;">
  </main>
  <footer>

  </footer>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What layout are you aiming for? Text vertically centered to the right of the image, and a line below them both? Or the line directly under the text? A picture or detailed description of your goal might help.

Comment: I want the image at the left the navigation at the right and the line I put is cutting off when to close I want the line almost exactly under the image to the image so can you help me with all of this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to offer an alternative method. There are many ways to achieve that layout, but I recommend [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). It can keep the logo and menu on the same row with the menu vertically centered.

I'm using `border-bottom` instead of `<hr>` and `<ul>` instead of `<table>` for the navigation.

Here's a demonstration:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.nav {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nav li {
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header>

    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/118/50/50" width="50" height="50" alt="">

    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

  </header>

  <main>
    Main
  </main>

  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>

</body>
```